# I can't open a CSV file (i want to open it without pandas) in pycharm

Tags: python

The following code is provided by my university to open a csv file:

```
import csv with open("groningenRestaurants.csv") as handler_csv_file: raw_content_file = csv.reader(handler_csv_file) table = list(raw_content_file)
```

However, when running this the following error occurs:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1250: : invalid continuation byte
```

how can i overcome this?

Comment: The file is not UTF-8, so you should explicitly add the encoding in `open` (as additional parameter)

Comment: What is the contents of your CSV file?

Comment: Specify an appropriate encoding to the *open()* function. Try Latin-1

Comment: @MichaelM. the content of the csv is file with restauranta in Groningen (a city), the address and the coordinates as columns

Comment: Is the CSV file available publicly? If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, try to specify another encoding than 'utf-8', e.g. 'latin-1', like this:

```
with open("groningenRestaurants.csv", encoding='latin-1') as handler_csv_file: 
   raw_content_file = csv.reader(handler_csv_file)
```

If you are not able to solve it this way, you could try the 'ignore' errors option and see what comes out:

```
with open("groningenRestaurants.csv", errors='ignore') as handler_csv_file: 
    raw_content_file = csv.reader(handler_csv_file)
```